# Add perspective and rotateY in Adobe Edge

Tags: css, css-transforms, adobe-edge

I'm trying to understand how to add perspective to an element and animate `rotateY` and `rotateX` properties, right now all I can do is do standard rotate (which is z axis) and skewX , skewY, which are giving me unsatisfactory results.

How can I achieve this?

[image]